# How can I modify request in spring mvc filter or interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There exists two common parameters data1 and data2 in my request, and I need decrypt them to 10 parameters, and use them in my controllers.

I tried replace the HttpServletRequest param to My Custom HttpServletRequestWrapper instance in filter. But I got a DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest instance instead of my HttpServletRequestWrapper instance. So I can't get the decrypted parameters in my controllers.
I also found that there is cannot change request param in HandlerInterceptorAdapter.

```
public class SecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //todo: convert data1,data2 to param1, ... param10
        logger.info("doFilterInternal 1 " + httpServletRequest);
        filterChain.doFilter(new CultureRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest), httpServletResponse);
        logger.info("doFilterInternal 2 "  + httpServletRequest);
    }
}

public class CultureRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public CultureRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        //todo:convert
        return super.getParameterValues(name);
    }

}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/req1"})
@ResponseBody
public JsonResult testreq(HttpServletRequest request) {
    logger.info("request:" + request);//get DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest
    logger.info("request param size:" + request.getParameterMap().size());//get 2 (data1,data2)
    String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
    ...
    String param10 = request.getParameter("param10");
}
```

Comment: How does the signature of you controller method look like now?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski  @RequestMapping(value = {"/req1"})@ResponseBody
public JsonResult testreq(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
    ...
    String param10 = request.getParameter("param10");
}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

**1)** Create a POJO which would reflect your 10 decoded values.

**2)** Decode the params in the filter/interceptor and populate the POJO with them.

**3)** Set the POJO as an attribute of the request:

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain){
        //convert data1,data2 to param1, ... param10 into a POJO

        httpServletRequest.setAttribute("decodedData", pojo);

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
```

**4)** Use the `@RequestAttribute` annotation on the controller methods in order to retrieve the POJO wherever you need to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/req1"})
@ResponseBody
public JsonResult testreq(@RequestAttribute("decodedData") PojoWith10Values pojo) {
```

Comment: There exist so many controller methods, and the request object been passed to services, so there may need a huge work to add a RequestAttribute parameter. Is there any simple plan?

Comment: You have to pass this data if you want to keep your services stateless

Comment: @fm927 did you find the solution? I am looking for something similar..