# How to rewrite Sort.Order parameters for Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to rewrite a sort query:

So far the query was: `?sort=lastname&sort=...`

```
@GetMapping
public void getPersons(..., Pageable pageable) {
   pageable.getSort().getOrderFor("lastname"); //TODO replace with 'surname'
}

@Entity
class PersonEntity {
     String lastname;
     //String surname;
}
```

Now database fields changed from `lastname` to `surname`. Thus I have to rewrite the sort query, but without having API users to change their bookmarks. So that `?sort=lastname` acts the same as `?sort=surname`.

How could I achieve that, because neither `Pageable` nor `Sort` has *setters*?

Of course, as suggested by @M. Deinum, I could rewrite the entire Pageable.Sort as follows. But is this really the solution?

```
    if (pageable != null
            && pageable.getSort() != null
            && pageable.getSort().isSorted()
            && pageable.getSort().getOrderFor("lastname") != null) {
        List<Sort.Order> orders = pageable.getSort().stream()
                .map(order -> {
                    String property = order.getProperty();
                    if (StringUtils.equals(property, "lastname")) 
                           property = "surname";
                    return new Sort.Order(order.getDirection(), property, order.getNullHandling());
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), Sort.by(orders));
   }
```

Comment: Recreate it if you detect that `lastname` is being used.

Comment: Why don't you put a request interceptor to replace sort=lastname with sort=surname ?

Comment: @GauravJeswani could you give an example? I mean, at which stage has the rewrite to happen?

Comment: Are you using SpringBoot?

Comment: yes that's why I added the tag `spring-boot` ;)

Comment: @M.Deinum but there might be some more sort parameters in the query. I will lose them then?

Comment: Of course I could rewrite the Sort query entirely, like I added code above. But is this really the solution so such a common usecase? I mean, it's not unusual to provide backwards compatibility.

Comment: You can create a `Pageable` based of another pageable and reconfigure. Just replace the `lastname` with `surname` everything else will be kept.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534344/how-can-i-modify-request-in-spring-mvc-filter-or-interceptor

Comment: @M.Deinum could you give an example on how to "create a pageable pased on another and reconfigure"? Is this different from what I posted in the question?

Comment: That should work what you have, or use `pageable.withSort` to simply pass the modified sort to the existing `Pageable`.

Comment: Also if this is JPA, why not keep the JPA model the same and simply add an `@Column(name="surname")` to the JPA field `lastname`? Then you don't need any of this.